# Paytm sdk ios integration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I set the delegate **PGTransactionDelegate** but it's showing an error like
view-controller does not conform with protocol "**PGTransactionDelegate**"

code:

Paytm target header in Bridging-Header

```
#import "PaymentsSDK.h
```

Delegate method in view-controller

```
// On Successful Payment
func didSucceedTransaction(controller: PGTransactionViewController, response: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {             
    print(response)
    print("Deducted amount :Rs. \(response["TXNAMOUNT"]!)")
    self.removeController(controller)
}

// On Failure
func didFailTransaction(controller: PGTransactionViewController, error: NSError, response: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(response)
    if response.count == 0 {
        print(response.description)
    }
    else if error != 0 {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.removeController(controller)
}

//On Cancellation
func didCancelTransaction(controller: PGTransactionViewController, error: NSError, response: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("Transaction has been Cancelled")
    self.removeController(controller)    
}

func didFinishCASTransaction(controller: PGTransactionViewController, response: [NSObject : AnyObject]) { 
    print(response);   
}
```

Comment: add  PGTransactionDelegate in your viewcontroller class

Comment: i have already added PGTransactionDelegate in my view controller still it's showing an error

Comment: Hello, did you help me on paytm integration all is working properly but getting defult page of paytm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recently updated your code to swift3.0, there might be some syntax change for the delegate function, Please check that.

Comment: i alredy check that it's ok if you have some suggestion please provide me.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct Paytm target header in Bridging-Header

#import "PaymentsSDK.h"

If you are using swift 3 or swift 4 then these method can resolve your problem

```
// On Successful Payment
func didSucceedTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    printLog(log: response)
}

// On Failure
func didFailTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, error: Error!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    printLog(log: response)
    printLog(log: error.localizedDescription)
}

//On Cancellation
func didCancelTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, error: Error!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    printLog(log: response)
    root.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```